# Globally implementation of google sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a ready script for google sheets and owner of that sheet. When I add my script and run, it is working. But when I add some more users (no matter of their rights and priveleges) that script is not working. Please help me to implement my script globally with no extra actions from another users - just open a sheet and it is working.

Tried googling, but, it is giving solutions with triggers, but couldn't find those menus to attach triggers to my google sheet. It asks for latest google sheets update, but also couldn't find the update menu as well. Please help me if anyone knows. I just need my script to be implemented globally for the whole sheet and for all users added further.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to be run as yourself (without the others users having to grant permissions), yes, you need to use Installed Triggers. I suggest you read the documentation, but here's a quick guide:

1. Go to Extensions - Apps Script

[image]

2. Go to that clock-like button third in the left, to open Triggers

[image]

3. Go to the down-right button: "+ Add trigger"

[image]

4. Choose what kind of trigger you need: to be run on open, on edit... be aware that you shouldn't have a function named "onEdit()"; call it something else and choose that in this menu. This way any function you want will be run as yourself

[image]

Comment: many thanks brother, it is working now!!! APPRECIATE YOUR SUPPORT, BIG THANKS!